# How to create a xml file on the client machine using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, google-chrome

How to create a xml file on the client machine using javascript or jquery. I need to write the xml file on the clients machine from my web application using javascript or jquery. How can i do so? and need it for atleast 3 browsers Firefox,Chrome and IE8+

Comment: you can create the file on server and make it downloadable for the client

Comment: Actualy [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086655/writing-xml-files-with-jquery) is described how to use jQuery for creating XML content. But I'm not sure if it's possible to write it to the file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but actually i need it to let my application work offline, and i dont need my data to be lost by clearing cache, so cannot use html5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use signed applet to write any file on the client side using your application. This is one of the best solution i have got till now.

Answer (score 1):

Creating files on the client side is not well supported in many browsers. The trick is to generate a string containing your XML, then encode it using base64 encoding, and redirect the browser to a [data: URL](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) which contains this base64 encoded data.

It is easier to create your file on the server and let the user download it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but actually i need it to let my application work offline, and i dont need my data to be lost by clearing cache, so cannot use html5