# translate php id's to xml for helping clients with itunes

Tags: php, xml, itunes

I am thinking this will be pretty easy but I can not find anything out there for this.

I am wanting to take a php page that my clients can edit and translate that into an itunes xml file. I guess my page does not need to be php, if that will hinder the translation

Is there a way to do this?

Here is the code. There is a lot more but you get the jist.

```
<div id="iTunes">
<p id="title" class="cms-editable">Your Channel tile</p>
<p id="author" class="cms-editable">Authors Name</p>
<p id="summary" class="cms-editable">Short Summary</p>
<p id="description" class="cms-editable">Short Description</p>

<div id="item" class="cms-repeatable" >
<p id="item-title" class="cms-editable">Your Podcast Title</p>
<p id="item-author" class="cms-editable">Podcast Author</p>
<p id="item-enclosure" class="cms-editable">http://www.Domain.org/podcast.mp3</p>

</div>
</div>
```

The XML would look like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>Your Channel tile</title>
<itunes:author>Authors Name</itunes:author>
<itunes:summary>Short Summary</itunes:summary>
<description>Short Description</description>
<item>
<title>Your Podcast Title</title>
<itunes:author>Podcast Author</itunes:author>
<enclosure url="http://www.Domain.org/podcast.mp3" length="" type="audio/x-mp3" />
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you possibly provide the XML schema? Or are you asking if there is one for iTunes?

Comment: I just edited the question with the XML.

Comment: I'd say load it in `DOMDocument` and  use `XSLTProcessor::transformToXML`, the xsl doesn't seem to hard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery and generate xml

Just for example you can generate xml like this

```
var xml = $('<?xml version="1.0"?><foo><bar></bar><bar></bar></foo>'); // Your xml
var xmlCont = $('<xml>'); // You create a XML container
xmlCont.append(xml); // You append your XML to the Container created in the main document

// Now you can append without problems to you xml
xmlCont.find('foo bar:first').append('<div />');

xmlCont.find('foo bar div'); // Test so you can see it works
```

And you can get all the element using this jquery command

```
$("#item > p").each(function() {
       //Create xml here 
    });
```

This is also an example please refer here for xml creation

[writing XML files with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086655/writing-xml-files-with-jquery)

and for getting all the child node from parent use this referance

[jQuery - get all divs inside a div with class ".container"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977699/jquery-get-all-divs-inside-a-div-with-class-container)

I hope this will help you to make your project